# what's the difference between "double" and "float" in c?

Tags: precision

I know that double has more precision than float and all that, but during lecture, my professor said 0.5 is a double. Could it be float too?

```
short int s;
int i;
long int l;
float f;
double d;
l = 2 * s + i * f - 0.5 * d;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is -0.0000 in c when using floats and double?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175218/what-is-0-0000-in-c-when-using-floats-and-double)

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205141/is-there-a-floating-point-literal-suffix-in-c-to-make-a-number-double-precisio), the type of a floating point literal (i.e. a number with a decimal point in it) is by default `double` unless it has a suffix of `f`:

> The type of a floating literal is double unless explicitly specified by a suffix. The suffixes f and F specify float, the suffixes l and L specify long double.

So, your professor appears to be spot on.  In the above expression `0.5` will be treated like a `double` by default.  I hope that you will get a high grade on the final exam.